# Pandas: Get rolling metric with adaptive window size

Tags: pandas

Edit: The answer to this question is indeed covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412805/python-pandas-rolling-functions), but the two questions are still different. I would never have found the other question using the search terms that came to my mind, because I didn't know that the `min_period` parameter would be the solution. Somebody else who has the same problem as me might find this question more easily than the other question.

I have a simple series of floats as a Pandas Series called `data`. I am producing a rolling metric over this series, in my case the rolling median, like to so:

```
data_smooth = data.rolling(window=25, center=True).median()
```

The problem with this is that the first and last twelve elements of `data_smooth` are `NaN`. Just for illustration:

```
> print(data_smooth)
0             NaN
1             NaN
2             NaN
3             NaN
4             NaN
5             NaN
6             NaN
7             NaN
8             NaN
9             NaN
10            NaN
11            NaN
12      17.853138
13      17.853138
14      17.939327
15      18.118628
16      18.392862
17      18.922707
18      18.922707
19      19.034254
20      19.034254
          ...
```

I, however, want the following behavior:

- I want the rolling median over a window size of `k` if a window of size `k` is possible.
- If a window of size `k` is not possible, I'd like to just take the maximum possible window.

For example, the rolling median for element 0 would be the median over the first 13 elements of the series (since I'm talking about a centered window in my case), the rolling median for element 1 would be the median over the first 14 elements of the series, etc., until a window of size 25 eventually becomes possible for element 12 and onward.

Comment: Try this:  `data.rolling(window=25, center=True, min_periods=1).median()`

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, that does the trick. I should have seen this myself. Thanks!